# Too Many Members in a Finitely Generated Module are Linearly Dependent

Tags: ring-theory, proof-verification, modules

I am new to module theory and as of now am not very comfortable with the subject. So can somebody please check whether my claim and its proof is okay?

Consider the following statement:

> Let $M$ be a finitely generated module over a nonzero ring (commutative with identity) $R$. Say $M$ can be generated by the set $\{x_1,\ldots, x_n\}\subseteq M$. Then given $n+1$ elements $y_1,\ldots, y_{n+1}\in M$, there exist $a_1, \ldots, a_{n+1}\in R$ not all zero such that
>   $$
> a_1y_1+\cdots+a_{n+1}y_{n+1}=0
> $$

**Purported Proof:**
Let $f:R^n\to M$ be the unique module homomorphism which sends $e_i=(0, \ldots,0, 1, 0,\ldots, 0)$ to $x_i$.
Then $f$ is surjective and we can thus find $t_1, \ldots, t_{n+1}\in R^n$ such that $f(t_j)=y_j$ for all $1\leq j\leq n+1$. Since rank of the free module $R^n$ is $n$, the members $t_1,\ldots, t_{n+1}$ must be linearly dependent.
So we have $a_1, \ldots, a_{n+1}\in R$ not all zero such that $a_1t_1+\cdots+a_{n+1}t_{n+1}=0$. Operating $f$ on both sides of the last equation, we get the desired result.

Comment: use the pigeonhole principle

Comment: @JonMarkPerry So is the statement correct? And I don't see how to apply PHP here? Can you give some details. Thanks.

Comment: is $a_1x_1$ right - should it be $a_1y_1$?

Comment: @JonMarkPerry Yes. Thanks. I edited it.

Comment: If you know why any $n+1$ elements of a free module of rank $n $ are linearly dependent, then your proof is true.

Comment: @darijgrinberg Yes I understand that well.